# obj-c pass struct pointer to arm assembly function - corruption

Tags: objective-c, pointers, assembly, arm, structure

I have a structure in obj-c.  I pass a pointer to this structure to an arm assembly function that i've written.  When i step into the code i see the pointer get successfully passed in and i can access and modify the values of the structure elements from within my asm code.  Life is good - until i return from the asm function.  After returning to the calling obj-c code the structure values are all hosed.  I can't figure out why.  Below are the relevant pieces of my code.

```
struct myValues{    // define my structure
int ptr2A;  // pointer to first float
float A;        
float B;        
float C;
float D;  
float E;
float F;
}myValues;

struct myValues my_asm(int ptr2a, float A, float B, float C, float D, float E, float F);  //  Prototype for the ASM function

…code here to set values of A-F...

float* ptr2A = &myValues.A;    //get the memory address where A is stored
myValues.ptr2A = ptr2A;         //put that address into myValues.ptr2A and pass to the ASM function


// now call the ASM code
myValues = my_asm(myValues.ptr2A, myValues.A, myValues.B, myValues.C, myValues.D, myValues.E, myValues.F);
```

Here is relevant part of my asm code:

```
mov r5, r1      //   r1 has pointer to the first float A
vdiv.f32 s3, s0, s0  //this line puts 1.0 in s3 for ease in debugging
vstr s3, [r5]  // poke the 1.0 into the mem location of A
bx lr
```

When i step through the code everything works as expected and i end up with a 1.0 in the memory location for A.  But, once i execute the return (bx lr) and return to the calling obj-c code the values in my structure become garbage.  I've dug through the ABI and AACPS (as successfully as a novice probably can) but can't get this figured out.  What is happening after that "bx lr" to wack the structure?

Below is "Rev 1" of my asm code.  I removed everything except these lines:

```
_my_asm:  
vdiv.f32 s3, s0, s0   // s3 = 1.0
vstr s3, [r1]
bx lr
```

Ok, this was solution for me.  Below is "Rev 2" of the relevant pieces of my obj-c code.  I was conflating passing a pointer with passing a copy of the structure - totally hose.  This code just passes a pointer to the first float in my struct...which my asm code picks up from general register r0.  Man, i'm hard headed.  ;-)

```
void my_asm2(int myptr);    // this is my prototype.
```

This is where i call the asm2 code from my obj-c code:

```
my_asm2(&myValues.A);
```

My asm2 code looks like this:

```
_my_asm2:                   ; @simple_asm_function
// r0 has pointer to the first float of my myValues structure
// Add prolog code here to play nice
vdiv.f32 s3, s0, s0   //result S3 = 1.0
vstr s3, [r0]         // poking a 1.0 back into the myValues.A value
// Add Epilog code here to play nice
bx lr
```

So, in summary, i can now pass a pointer to my structure myValues to my ASM code and inside my ASM code i can poke new values back into those memory locations.  When i return to my calling obj-c code everything is as expected.  Thanks to those who helped me fumble along with this hobby.  :-)

Comment: It sounds like you are failing to restore something before returning: *Subroutines must preserve the contents of r4 to r11 and the stack pointer*.  Hard to say more without seeing the rest of the routine.

Comment: After reading your post I whittled my asm function down to just 3 lines (see "Rev 1" above).  I don't touch any general register or the sp at all.  Still getting same results.  I step through the code and get a 1.0 in the memory location as expected - then i step across the "bx lr" and when i get returned to my calling obj-c code the values in the structure are garbage.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARM assembler, but since you pass arguments to the function, don't you have to restore the stack before/after returning?

Comment: Hi Amin - the assembler is LLVM as i am using Xcode 8.0 to build code for an iPhone 4.  I'm not a real programmer - just playing around with ASM on the ARM processors inside the iPhones.  Your comment helped me think more basically and solve this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @relayman357 It's a good practice here to answer your own question if you happened to solve your problem yourself. Might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to simply pass a pointer (that points to the memory location of the first float variable in the structure) to the assembly function.  Then, any changes the assembly function makes to those memory locations will be intact upon returning to the calling function. Note that this applies to the situation when you are calling assembly code and want that code to operate on an existing data structure (myValues in this case).